# Insert com ajax no onclick

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Gostaria de fazer um insert apartir do onclick com ajax e ja trazer o resutado para o texto deste botão.

Exemplificando é botão para curtir no caso cada click soma +1 ;

```
function curti(id,identify){
var base = 'idd='+id;
$.post({
    url:("ajax/curtir.php"),
    dataType:"json",
    data: base,
    success:function(dados){
        $("#"+identify).html(dados[index].curtir);
    }})}
```

Comment: você está com erro no javascript ou no  php ? especifique melhor sua duvida poste o seu retorno o que você está recebendo no  ajax ? você já olhou seu debug do navegador se tem  algum erro no  chome é so aperta o f12 e ir em console

Comment: na verdade nao acontece nada, nao entendo muito de ajax quero saber uma forma correta de realizar esta operação

Comment: jquery.js:9664 POST http://kingofeletro.com.br/3/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)send @ jquery.js:9664ajax @ jquery.js:9215m.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:9361curti @ (index):258onclick @ (index):270
13owl.carousel.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefinedrun @ owl.carousel.min.js:1e @ jquery.js:548e.update @ owl.carousel.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ owl.carousel.min.js:1e @ jquery.js:548

Comment: Agora está funcionando mas não está enviando o id do registro no onclick

function curti(id,identify){
 $.ajax({
  url:("ajax/curtir.php"),
  type: "POST",
  data: "udid="+id,
  success:function(data){
   $("#"+identify).html(data);
  }})}



echo "<button id='$guidcurti' role='button' onClick='curti($guid,$guidcurti)' class='btn btn-default fa fa-thumbs-o-up'>($curtir)</button>";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consegui resolver, vou deixar o método caso alguém esteja buscando como fazer

Função Javascript/Ajax

```
function curti(codigo,identify){
$.ajax({
    url:("ajax/curtir.php"),
    type: "POST",
    data: {"udid": codigo},
    success:function(data){
        $("#"+identify).html("("+data+")");
    }})}
```

Função PHP

```
<?php
   header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   include('../class/mysql_crud.php');
   $id = (isset($_POST['udid'])) ? (int)$_POST['udid'] : 0;
   $db = new Database();
   $db->connect();
   $db->sql("SELECT * FROM musicas_home WHERE guid = $id");
   $res = $db->getResult();
   foreach($res as $output){
     $curtirv = $output["curtir"];
   }
  $curtir = ($curtirv + 1);
  $db->update('musicas_home',array('curtir'=>$curtir),'guid='.$id);

  echo json_encode($curtir);
```

Botão chamando a função com onclick

```
echo "<button id='$guidcurti' role='button' onClick='curti($guid,$guidcurti)' class='btn btn-default fa fa-thumbs-o-up'>($curtir)</button>";
```

Com certeza tem como melhorar muita coisa, quem quiser editar a vontade.

Answer (score 0):

Voca acha necessário retornar um Json?
Voce poderia simplesmente colocar um $("#"+identify).html (dados) e no arquivo que faz tua função você dava echo no html. Exemplo: echo "Sucesso . Esse span ja iria aparecer no seu html principal.